# How to convert an existing JTable to a JTable result of a method?

Tags: java, swing

I have a JFrame generated by netbeans with a JTable1 in it. I have a method that accepts a JTable and returns a JTable2 with another stuff.

I want to know how to make JTable1(JFrame) to JTable2(Method)?

```
public static JTable realTimeFilter(JTable table) {

    TableRowSorter<TableModel> rowSorter = new TableRowSorter<>(table.getModel());
    table.setRowSorter(rowSorter);
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(60);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(60);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(502);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(130);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(130);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(130);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(70);
    return table;
}
```

Comment: `JTable1 = realTimeFilter(JTable1)` and then update in view for new values of `JTable1` using `JTable1.repaint()`.

Comment: Thanks you very much!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `repaint()` method to reflect the changes made in your table.

```
JTable1 = realTimeFilter(JTable1);
//JTable1.repaint();  no need for this method as i got to know from comments on this answer
```

Or, you can more dynamically notify your table about the changes using,

`JTable1.getModel().fireTableDataChanged()`

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableDataChanged%28%29).

Comment: This seems unnecessary; updates to a table's model should cause the _model_ to fire such events; the table should then update itself in response.

Comment: @trashgod Yup , when I call realTimeFilter() it updates the JTable , and even with the realtimefilter , there are no need to repaint(). If you need all the code , let me know.

Answer (score 0):

`JTable1 = realTimeFilter(JTable1);`
As Working fine no need to `repaint()` the JTable.